# How to calculate input from an array

Tags: java

I'm having trouble with this array I'm working on. In the for loop, I need to somehow calculate an on base percentage. The element at index 0 will store the OBP. How can I retain the information the user inputs to calculate the OBP? Thank you.

```
     for (int index = 0; index < years.length; index++)
     {
       System.out.print("For Year " + (index +1 ) + "\nEnter number of hits: ");
       years[index] = keyboard.nextInt();

       System.out.print("For Year " + (index +1) + "\nEnter number of walks: ");
       years[index] = keyboard.nextInt();

       System.out.print("For Year" + (index +1) + "\nEnter the number of times player"
                          + "has been hit by a pitch:");
       years[index] = keyboard.nextInt();

       System.out.print("For Year" + (index +1) + "\nEnter the number of at bats:");
       years[index] = keyboard.nextInt();

       System.out.print("For Year" + (index +1) + "\nEnter the number of sacrafice flies" 
                          + "that year: ");
       years[index] = keyboard.nextInt();

     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to store the values entered by the user in a variable.  Instead of having an array of inputs (which is one way of doing it) - you can simply store each value in a separate variable and then do the calculation at the end.

See my sample code below:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    // let's take incoming values from the user for our calculations
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    // we'll use this array to store the values entered by the user
    // in position zero of the array we'll store the OBP
    // in positions 1-5 we'll store the inputs as entered by the uesr
    float[] values = new float[6];

    // we'll use this flag to determin if we should ask the user input again or quit the program
    boolean letsDoThisAgain = true;

    while (letsDoThisAgain){
        System.out.println("Enter a Year: ");
        int year = keyboard.nextInt();

        System.out.println("For Year " + year + ", enter number of:");
        System.out.println("Hits: ");
        values[1] = keyboard.nextFloat();

        System.out.println("Walks: ");
        values[2] = keyboard.nextFloat();

        System.out.println("Number of times player has been hit by a pitch: ");
        values[3] = keyboard.nextFloat();

        System.out.println("Number of at bats: " );
        values[4] = keyboard.nextFloat();

        System.out.println("Number of sacrifice flies: ");
        values[5] = keyboard.nextFloat();

        // calculate the OBP
        values[0] = (values[1] + values[2] + values[3] - values[5] ) / values[4]; // or however you calculate it

        System.out.println("OBP: " + values[0]);

        System.out.println("------");
        System.out.println("Do you want to do it again? (y/n): ");
        String quitOrDoItAgain = keyboard.next();

        if( "n".equalsIgnoreCase(quitOrDoItAgain)){
            letsDoThisAgain = false;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Thanks for playing... Good Bye!");
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. I should've added this in the question and that is my fault. This assignment is an introduction to arrays, so it would have to be used through an array, unfortunately.

Comment: @Jusinr518 ah, I see... I’ll update my answer when I get back to my desk

Comment: @Jusinr518 I have updated my answer to use an array to store inputs instead of individual variables

Comment: Thank you so much for taking time out of your day to assist me with my issue. This is perfect and will definitely lead me towards the right direction.

Comment: @Jusinr518 I am glad I could help. Dont' forget to upvote useful answers :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest a HashMap inside a HashMap for this use case.

Before loop:

```
HashMap<Integer, HashMap<String, Integer>> years = new HashMap<>();
HashMap<String, Integer> entry = new HashMap<>();
```

For every input from user's keyboard (example):

```
entry.put("hits", 5);
years.put(2019, entry);

entry.put("walks", 10);
years.put(2019, entry);
```

In the end you get a result such as:

```
{2019={hits=5, walks=10}}
```

Retrieving results is simple too:

```
// retrieve map of data for a specific year:
years.get(2019)

result: {hits=5, walks=10}

// retrieve specific data for a specific year:
years.get(2019).get("hits")

result: 5
```

Comment: Of course, I'd personally create a simple class e.g. User and have separate fields for each data type.

Answer (score 0):

By the usage of a proper data structure like `Map<string year, object playerstats> including OBP calculation on the object player stats before storing` but this is an in-memory solution only last till the program is running if you like persistent then look on the database side

Also from the way you have presented your code it seems you are over-writing the value at year[index] always.

if you just want to use an array, then go  like

```
years[index] = year[index] (math operation) keyboard.nextInt()
```